# add incrementing date to mysql table for a range of dates

Tags: mysql, database, automation

I created a table that needs to store the date and different variables so that I can use this as a base for a large dataset. I need to pre fill in the dates for the dataset so there are no missing values.
table:

```
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field    | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Alt      | smallint  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| Lat      | smallint  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| Lon      | smallint  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| Rate     | float     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| dateTime | timestamp | NO   | PRI | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |       |
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

I need to add rows from "2000-01-01 00:00:00 to "2019-12-30 00:00:00" that increment by 3 hours and has all other variables as null. And I want to make the process as automated as possible so I can let it run and it will fill out the rows for the date range

for example the rows would be
null, null,null,null 2000-01-01 00:00:00
null, null,null,null 2000-01-01 03:00:00
null, null,null,null 2000-01-01 06:00:00

Comment: what does `select version();` give?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `DATE_ADD` and shell script, this is far beyond optimal, but works:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (dateTime) VALUES ('2000-01-01 00:00:00')
```

And then with a little shell script:

```sh
for X in {1..999}; do
    mysql -e "SELECT dateTime INTO @d FROM a ORDER BY dateTime DESC LIMIT 1; INSERT INTO a (dateTime) VALUES (DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 3 HOUR));"
done
```

You can even made a select before to know the current date inside the loop.

Comment: The `-e` executes a command on server and exits.

Comment: When I tried this I got an error ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected. is the @d supposed to be the name of the database? I was able to get through the access issues

Comment: Yes, I made an example, add your database before `-e` like this: `mysql mydb -e '...'`